# ToolBar class not found error

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement a toolbar in my android project by replacing actionbar and I am getting

> android.support.v7.widget.ToolBar class not found error.

I have upgraded my sdk to Android 5.1 and also have installed android support Library and   Android support repository. Some one please help me solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.. :-)

Comment: can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: Open your `build.gradle` and check whether ` compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+' present in dependency. Note : Version varies. You need to replace based on your ver.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, well I am working on this project using eclipse and there isn't any gradle file in this project. Am I doing it wrong some were? I am a beginner.

Comment: Add appcompat-v7 lib in your project and add it to build path of the project. @JobinPhilip

Comment: Ok. Check this out (Support Library Setup)[https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html]

Comment: Hi all , Thanks for the quick responses friends. I have already added android-support-v4.jar  and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to libs folder and to the build path. configured the build path to select these to jar files and unchecked the dependencies option. Still the problem persists. @pooja Thank you once again for the support.

Comment: @JobinPhilip Have you tried cleaning project or restart eclipse?

Comment: well it got solved when I stopped setting minimum sdk version to 14 instead of 8 that comes by default. now the Appcompat_v7 library is getting created and attached automatically to the project without manually importing it from the sdk and I did the build path work as it was said in [developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html] .Thanks a Ton dear all .. @Pooja